# extra double quotes is added when i get value from propertis file in Java

Tags: selenium

When i am printing value of browserName from child class its showing    "chrome" not chrome.(I am reading value from properties file"

```
public WebDriver initializeDriver() throws IOException
{
Properties prop=new Properties();
FileInputStream fs=new FileInputStream("D:\\data.properties");
prop.load(fs);
String browserName=prop.getProperty("browser");
System.out.println(browserName);
}

data.propeties
browser=chrome
```

Comment: I ran your code and got chrome. Without quotes. Try to check your properties once more, maybe there browser="chrome"

Comment: thanks Kara4k , issue was with properties file. I have given path of properties file which was under different project